# Set the facebook comment box when clicking on like button

Tags: php, css, facebook, facebook-like

I have installed and set-up a facebook like button for each posts of my website [Socatchy!](http://socatchy.net/percy-lau-mystery-and-creation/)

But when I click on the "Like" button, the comment box to add a comment to your like on your Facebook account doesn't show up correctly, I mean that it is getting cut.

Here is the link which shows what I mean :

[BUG](http://socatchy.net/percy-lau-mystery-and-creation/)

If you click at the bottom of the page on the "Like" button, the Facebook comment box seems to be cut.

I don't know if I have to add something to my PHP or CSS files, or to set something in the codes.

Any help is appreciated,

I thank you in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the width you are setting on the Facebook plugin.

```
.zilla-share > div.fb_edge_widget_with_comment { top: 0px; width: 90px !important; overflow: visible; }

.zilla-share > div { width: 80px !important; }
```

Both of these are contributing to your problem. Removing those properties fixes your bug. I remember you were trying to get them to be all in a single line, which is why you had a width set. I recommended wrapping every plugin with an additional `div`, and styling that instead. Trying to style the elements that the plugin gives you never goes well for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response!
Indeed, when I remove those properties the Facebook comment box works perfectly!

The next problem is to wrap every plugin with an additional "div" in order to style them:

I have to create those classes with a "div" and put them in my plugin PHP file or in my Wordpress theme file ?

Have you some example of creating a class in PHP ?

Thank you (again) very much,

Regards